# Random Forest Variable Importance Plot Discrepancy?

Tags: r, random-forest

I am using the following code to get Random Forest variable importance plot:

```
statRF <- randomForest(formula = Trend ~ ., data = data[,features], sampsize=c(600,600,600),mtry=6, ntree=500, importance=TRUE)
varImpPlot(statRF, cex=1.2)
```

[image]

However, when I try to extract Mean Decrease in Accuracy I get completely different variable importance

```
statRF$importance
              Decreasing  Increasing   No Trend         MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
EcoRegion      0.005331568 0.002025101 6.025702e-05         0.0009792462         6.340508
Geology        0.009487879 0.004385796 4.427072e-03         0.0047468217        25.811581
Avg1980        0.068535362 0.026512398 6.766761e-03         0.0165637391       171.622158
Fire_Group     0.114414044 0.023774639 1.941874e-02         0.0269273991        52.122888
FLOW_SUM       0.009836593 0.009120500 5.692553e-03         0.0069617922       130.574740
MEAN_SLOPE     0.011427702 0.003421026 2.723633e-03         0.0034971800       134.810582
MEAN_ELEVATION 0.071074497 0.027537933 3.030051e-02         0.0321650097       167.462789
NEAR_DIST      0.018364729 0.004711747 9.081642e-04         0.0031616073       133.859939
Latitude       0.065935569 0.035386208 2.414563e-02         0.0301581377       176.920755
Longtitude     0.098719411 0.060942430 4.483657e-02         0.0530569867       200.474059

sort(statRF$importance[,4], decreasing=TRUE)
    Longtitude MEAN_ELEVATION       Latitude     Fire_Group        Avg1980       FLOW_SUM        Geology 
  0.0530569867   0.0321650097   0.0301581377   0.0269273991   0.0165637391   0.0069617922   0.0047468217 
    MEAN_SLOPE      NEAR_DIST      EcoRegion 
  0.0034971800   0.0031616073   0.0009792462
```

Notably, elevation is now the second "most important" variable instead of the fourth and a few other switches in the postion of different variables.

Wondering if the `varImpPlot` function is plotting something different than the MeanDecreaseAccuracy variable from the random forest model? If so how do I get those values?

**EDIT:**
I can get the MeanDecreaseAccuracy values from the first plot with the following code:

```
var.imp <- varImpPlot(statRF)
var.imp <- as.data.frame(var.imp)

var.imp
                  MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
EcoRegion                  4.939973         6.340508
Geology                   16.326295        25.811581
Avg1980                   34.301641       171.622158
Fire_Group                49.419724        52.122888
FLOW_SUM                  18.991762       130.574740
MEAN_SLOPE                12.053575       134.810582
MEAN_ELEVATION            47.251207       167.462789
NEAR_DIST                 10.508457       133.859939
Latitude                  52.898975       176.920755
Longtitude                74.645221       200.474059
```

But I am still unclear why the scale and order is different in `statRF$importance`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable importance in the final plot are scaled by their standard errors, if you check the [help page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-14/topics/varImpPlot) for varImp plot, the default argument is `scale=TRUE` which is passed to the function `importance`. To get back the scaled values, you can use the `importance()` function like below:

```
library(randomForest)
set.seed(111)
fit = randomForest(Species ~ .,data=iris,importance=TRUE)
```

[image]

```
importance(fit,scale=TRUE)
                setosa versicolor virginica MeanDecreaseAccuracy
Sepal.Length  6.716993  7.4654657  7.697842            10.869088
Sepal.Width   4.581990 -0.5208697  4.224459             3.772957
Petal.Length 22.155981 33.0549839 27.892363            33.272150
Petal.Width  22.497643 31.4966353 31.589361            33.123064
             MeanDecreaseGini
Sepal.Length         9.333510
Sepal.Width          2.425592
Petal.Length        43.324744
Petal.Width         44.146107
```

Or to see how this is calculated, you do:

```
fit$importance[,1:4] / fit$importanceSD

                setosa versicolor virginica MeanDecreaseAccuracy
Sepal.Length  6.716993  7.4654657  7.697842            10.869088
Sepal.Width   4.581990 -0.5208697  4.224459             3.772957
Petal.Length 22.155981 33.0549839 27.892363            33.272150
Petal.Width  22.497643 31.4966353 31.589361            33.123064
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know of any reason to used unscaled variable importance?

Comment: it's the actual decrease in accuracy. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197827/how-to-interpret-mean-decrease-in-accuracy-and-mean-decrease-gini-in-random-fore

Comment: However, this measure by itself can be unstable (see the last answer in the linked post). Hence you scale it by the standard error to get something more sensible.. I am trying to find the actual link